# Euclidean algorithm for polynomials over a field

Tags: polynomials

Let $f$ and $g$ be polynomials in $F[X]$, with $F$ a field and let $d(X)$ be their $\gcd$. Euclid's algorithm constructs polynomials $a(X),b(X)$ such that:
$$a(X)f(X)+b(X)g(X)=d(X);\quad\deg(a)<\deg(g);\quad\deg(b)<\deg(f).$$

I can understand how the algorithm works. My problem concerns with the second part of the statement, the one related to degrees. For example, I can't prove $\deg(a)<\deg(g)$.

My book says: let $af+bg=d$. If $\deg(a)\geq\deg(g)$, write $a=gq+r$ with $\deg(r)<\deg(g)$, then
$$rf+(b+qf)g=d$$
and $b+qf$ automatically has degree less than $f$. I can't understand this last statement: ...automatically has degree less than $f$, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, assume neither $f$ nor $g$ are constant (they are nonzero by assumption, since we are talking about their degrees), otherwise the claim is either trivial, or even not true if *both* are constant.

The degree of $r f$ is *less than* $\deg(g)+\deg(f)$. If $\deg(b + q f) \ge \deg(f)$, there's no way for the leading term of $(b + q f) g$, which then has degree *at least* $\deg(f)+\deg(g)$, to cancel out with a term of $r f$ to give you $d$, which has degree at most $\max(\deg(f), \deg(g)) < \deg(f)+\deg(g)$ (recall that neither $f$ nor $g$ have degree $0$).